# Count(table.column) does not consider the null values of the column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to count all the values of the columns regardless of NULL values in it.
i have tried this query.

```
SELECT COUNT(t1) FROM Bilal b WHERE b.t1 IS NULL
```

**Result** =0

```
t1  t2
1   1
NULL    NULL

SELECT COUNT(t1) FROM Bilal b
```

**Result** =1

Comment: This is how the behaviour of `count()` is defined (and most definitely documented)

Comment: What value do you want?

Comment: You can [abuse this property for some fun](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561541/sql-merging-4-queries-to-one/23565994#23565994)

Answer (score 0):

That is known behavior.

Count(*) will include NULLS

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises since you are counting a specific column (`SELECT COUNT(t1)`). Instead, you can use  `SELECT COUNT(*)` or `SELECT COUNT(1)`, which will both include `NULL` values. If you are interested in the mechanics, read [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/benjamin/archive/2013/12/27/sql-tip-counting-null-values.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(nvl(t1,0)) from table;
```